# Fast Popcount instruction or Hamming distance for binary array?

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation, hamming-distance

I'm implementing on Visual Studio 2010 C++

I have two binary arrays. For example,

```
array1[100] = {1,0,1,0,0,1,1, .... }
array2[100] = {0,0,1,1,1,0,1, .... }
```

To calculate the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between `array1` and `array2`,
`array3[100]` stores the `xor` result of `array1` and `array2`.

Then I have to count the number of `1` bits in `array3`. To do this, I know I can use the `__popcnt` instruction.

For now, I'm doing something like below:

```
popcnt_result = 0;
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    popcnt_result = popcnt_result + __popcnt(array3[i]);
}
```

It shows a good result but is slow. How can I make it faster?

Comment: Are those arrays of `int` and do they only contain the values `0` or `1`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to represent each "array entry" by just 1 bit (not byte)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes I have binary integer array, so only 0 or 1

Comment: @reuben Yeah I want to do that..

Answer (score 3):

`array3` seems a bit wasteful, you're accessing a whole extra 400 bytes of memory that you don't need to. I would try comparing what you have with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    result += (array1[i] ^ array2[i]);   // could also try != in place of ^
}
```

If that helps at all, then I leave it as an exercise for the reader how to apply both this change *and* duskwuff's.

Comment: and let the loop-unrolling games begin to really squeeze every last performance out this algorithm :-)

Answer (score 2):

As implemented, the `__popcnt` call is not helping. It's actually slowing you down.

`__popcnt` counts the number of set bits in its argument. You're only passing in one element, which looks like it's guaranteed to be 0 or 1, so the result (also 0 or 1) is not useful. Doing this would be slightly faster:

```
popcnt_result += array3[i];
```

Depending on how your array is laid out, you may or may not be able to use `__popcnt` in a cleverer way. Specifically, if your array consists of one-byte elements (e.g, `char`, `bool`, `int8_t`, or similar), you could perform a population count on four elements at a time:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
    uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *) &array3[i];
    popcnt_result += __popcnt(*p);
}
```

(Note that this depends on the fact that 100 is divisible evenly by 4. You'd have to add some special-case handling for the last few elements otherwise.)

If the array consists of larger values, such as `int`, though, you're out of luck, and there's still no guarantee that this will be any faster than the naïve implementation above.

Comment: Doesn't the proposed change violate strict aliasing?

Comment: Yes, it does -- it's doing something that's fundamentally "icky", though, so I don't believe there's any way around it.

Comment: One way around it is `uint32_t u; memcpy(&u, array3+i, sizeof u);`, then check whether or not the optimizer is smart enough to eliminate `u` and just load 4 bytes from the array into a register for popcounting. I don't know whether or not MSVC is, but because you haven't violated strict aliasing, it won't do anything irritating like zapping `array` before the loop, because it thinks it's unused, and using the memory for something else. Mind you, I also don't know whether or not MSVC is smart enough to do anything irritating when you violate strict aliasing...

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays only contain two values (`0` or `1`) the Hamming distance is just the number of positions where corresponding values are different. This can be done in one pass using `std::inner_product` from the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int array1[100] = { 1,0,1,0,0,1,1, ... };
    int array2[100] = { 0,0,1,1,1,0,1, ... };

    int distance = std::inner_product(array1, array1 + 100, array2, 0, std::plus<int>(), std::not_equal_to<int>());

    std::cout << "distance=" << distance << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```